# How to fix the uploading files with Next-js v14.0.4 and react-filepond v7.1.2 results in corrupted files

Tags: typescript, next.js

I am having an issue uploading JPEG image files with Next-js v14.0.4 and react-filepond v7.1.2. When I upload an image, the upload process succeeds, but the downloaded image becomes corrupted and cannot be displayed. I have tried uploading images with different sizes and formats, but the issue persists.

Here is the code I am using for the upload:

```
// fileUpload.tsx

"use client";
import React from "react";
import { FilePond, FilePondProps, registerPlugin } from "react-filepond";
import "filepond/dist/filepond.min.css";

import FilePondPluginImageExifOrientation from "filepond-plugin-image-exif-orientation";
import FilePondPluginImagePreview from "filepond-plugin-image-preview";
import "filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.css";
import { FilePondInitialFile } from "filepond";

registerPlugin(FilePondPluginImageExifOrientation, FilePondPluginImagePreview);

interface FileUploadProps {
    allowMultiple?: FilePondProps["allowMultiple"];
    maxFiles?: FilePondProps["maxFiles"];
    labelIdle?: FilePondProps["labelIdle"];
}

export default function FileUpload({
    allowMultiple,
    maxFiles,
    labelIdle,
}: FileUploadProps) {
    const [files, setFiles] = React.useState<FilePondInitialFile[]>([]);

    const handleOnUpdate = (files: any) => {
        // setFiles();
    };

    return (
        <FilePond
            files={files}
            onupdatefiles={handleOnUpdate}
            allowMultiple={allowMultiple}
            maxFiles={maxFiles}
            server={{
                process: "/admin/api/v1/upload-file",
            }}
            name="files"
            labelIdle={
                labelIdle ??
                'Drag & Drop your files or <span class="filepond--label-action">Browse</span>'
            }
        />
    );
}
```

```
// app/admin/api/v1/upload-file/route.ts

import { responseJson } from '@/services/response-object';
import { promises as fs } from "fs";
import path from 'path';

export async function POST(request: Request) {
    try {
        const blob = await request.blob();
        const arrayBuffer = await blob.arrayBuffer();
        const temporaryDir = path.join(process.cwd(), "public", "tmp", "filename.jpg");

        console.log(arrayBuffer);

        const dataView = new DataView(arrayBuffer);
        const buffer = new Uint8Array(dataView.buffer);

        fs.writeFile(temporaryDir, buffer);
    
        return responseJson({ status: "success", message: "File moved successfully" });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error moving file:", error);
        return responseJson({ status: "error", message: "Failed to move file" });
    }
}
```